# Share Audiences data from Analytics to Notifications #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to send a notification (from a new firebase console) to the particular audience. But when I select Audience in the target dropbox I got this message. The same message when I'm trying to set Conversion events.

> Audience data isn’t currently being shared from Analytics

The message doesn't appear while selecting Language or Version.

How to share Audience data from Analytics to Notifications?

Comment: A/B testing feature of Firebase (Remote config and notifications) also doesn't show all the metrics, such as revenue and retention, unless the below data sharing is enabled for Analytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to log in your [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and go in your settings.
Then click on Analytics and you should have the screen below that let you managed how your audiences are shared between firebase products.
[image]